# Json data Match Fixtures Group by Pool number

Tags: php, json, sorting, group-by

Further to this Question, [Json data Group by value using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952785/json-data-group-by-value-using-php)

now i want to group the fixture by pool number
Json Data is here

> ```
> {
> "items":[
>     {"id":129481,"draw_id":27718,"number":1,"pool":-1,
>         "fixtures":[
>             {"id":"529348","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129481,"number":1,"round_info":"PRE QUARTER FINALS","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"},
>             {"id":"529349","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129481,"number":1,"round_info":"PRE QUARTER FINALS","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"},
>             {"id":"529352","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129481,"number":1,"round_info":"PRE QUARTER FINALS","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"}
>         ],
>         "byes":[]
>     },
>     {"id":129493,"draw_id":27718,"number":1,"pool":1,
>         "fixtures":[
>             {"id":"529390","name":"Service Organization vs Friends Association","round":{"id":129493,"number":1,"round_info":"League","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"},
>             {"id":"529391","name":"Service Organization vs Shaheen Makhdoom","round":{"id":129493,"number":1,"round_info":"League","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"}
>         ],
>         "byes":[]
>     },
> {"id":129492,"draw_id":27718,"number":1,"pool":2,
>         "fixtures":[
>             {"id":"529387","name":"Prince Manki vs E.C.B","round":{"id":129492,"number":1,"round_info":"League","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"},
>             {"id":"529388","name":"Prince Manki vs Moon Star Sports Center","round":{"id":129492,"number":1,"round_info":"League","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"}
>         ],
>         "byes":[]
>     },
> {"id":129482,"draw_id":27718,"number":2,"pool":-1,
>         "fixtures":[
>             {"id":"529356","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129482,"number":2,"round_info":"Quarter Finals","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"},                
>             {"id":"529357","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129482,"number":2,"round_info":"Quarter Finals","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture"}
>         ],
>         "byes":[]},
>     {"id":129483,"draw_id":27718,"number":3,"pool":-1,
>         "fixtures":[
>             {"id":"529360","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129483,"number":3,"round_info":null,"published_at":"2016-11-10T20:32:50+13:00","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture","_index":"fixtures","_version":null,"sort":[1481054400000,529360],"highlight":null,"_explanation":null},
>             {"id":"529359","name":"TBC vs TBC","round":{"id":129483,"number":3,"round_info":null,"published_at":"2016-11-10T20:32:50+13:00","published":true},"match_result":null,"matches":[],"officials":[],"_score":null,"_type":"fixture","_index":"fixtures","_version":null,"sort":[1481077800000,529359],"highlight":null,"_explanation":null}
>         ],
>         "byes":[]
>     }
> ],
> "meta":{"total_pages":1}
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$groupedItems = [];
$items = $json['items'];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $pool = $item['pool'];
    $groupedItems[$pool][] = $item;
}
ksort($groupedItems);
var_dump($groupedItems);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)