# How to return no particular data found in PHP to JSON call

Tags: php, json

Since there are different results from users input from API i need to print the message that there are no results for particular element and print the others for which there is. For example i would like to say that there are no results for this variable: $model = $jfo ->engine->valve->timing;
Here is my code so far below and here is the link to the API:
http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/1GCGG25U261243927?fmt=json&api_key=2jwwaax2sc4kuq7vg7ud79rc

```
<?php

//ini_set("display_errors",1);

//exit;

$datvin="";
$title="";
$posts="";
$mds="";
$model="";
if (isset($_POST['vin'])){
$datvin=trim($_POST['vin']);
$json_file = file_get_contents('http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/'.$datvin.'?fmt=json&api_key=2jwwaax2sc4kuq7vg7ud79rc');
// convert the string to a json object
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);
if ($jfo != '' && $jfo !== null) {
// read the title value
$title = $jfo->make->name;
// copy the posts array to a php var
$posts = $jfo->make->id;
$mds = $jfo->years[0]->year;
$model = $jfo ->engine->valve->timing;


}else {

    $model="not found";
}


}


?>
 <form role="form" action="index.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="VIN" class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Enter your VIN</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VIN" name="vin" placeholder="Enter your VIN" required="required">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-centered"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Test VIN</button>
        </form>

        <div><?php echo $model; ?></div>
```

Comment: What does this line return  "$model = $jfo ->engine->valve->timing;"?

Comment: I need the PHP script to print the result that there are no results for that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//ini_set("display_errors",1);

//exit;

$datvin="";
$title="";
$posts="";
$mds="";
$model="";
if (isset($_POST['vin'])){
$datvin=trim($_POST['vin']);
@$str = file_get_contents('http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/'.$datvin.'?fmt=json&api_key=2jwwaax2sc4kuq7vg7ud79rc');
// convert the string to a json object
$json = json_decode($str, true);

//echo count($json);
 //key to search
 $json['vin'];
 //show results
if($_POST['vin'] ==$json['vin']){
        echo "Model is here!";
        echo $json['make']['id'];
        echo $json['make']['name'];
        echo $json['make']['niceName'];
        echo $json['categories']['market'];
        echo $json['model']['id'];
        echo $json['model']['name'];
        echo $json['model']['niceName'];
    }
    else {

        $model="Model not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution for your problem is in $json['key'];  if you have more element in the comment there is a count(array); if you need loop for more elements. (Y)

Comment: This hasn't solved the problem if i add to the list some element which doesn't exist for particular VIN. Maybe it would be better to loop through all elements in JSON without naming them in PHP file?

Comment: I dont understand very well what you want in this case with my code if the vin number exist show the result else no! can you are more specific and detail better your question? please?

Comment: It seems the thing i was looking for was array_key_exists

Comment: you can do a foreach or for --look the code there is a count the result is 14   keys you cando a foreach or for for more elements . Add more element to the json to try. I've do a similar case here read this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109055/json-data-group-by-team-name-with-php/40568221#40568221

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at it.